# Display the name instead of the id in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel-10

Please find below the screenshots for the reference;

[image]

On the above Screenshot 1 displays the users dropdown to search the specific user and their repective orders.

[image]

On the above Screenshot 2 when the particular user is selected then the respective orders belongs to the user is displayed which is fine but the problem is that it is displaying id of the User but not the name when no orders is present for the respective user.

report_by_user.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.admin_dashboard')
@section('admin')

<div class="page-content">
                <!--breadcrumb-->
                <div class="page-breadcrumb d-none d-sm-flex align-items-center mb-3">
                    <div class="breadcrumb-title pe-3">Ecommerce Report</div>
                    <div class="ps-3"> 
                        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 p-0">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="bx bx-home-alt"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Ecommerce Report</li>
                            </ol>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                     
                </div>
                <!--end breadcrumb-->
                 
                <hr/>
                 
 


<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-1 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-3">
         

 <form method="post" action="{{ route('search-by-user')}}">
        @csrf
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                 
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Search By User</h5>
                     

      <label class="form-label">Select User:</label>
        <select name="user" class="form-select mb-3" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected="">Open this select User</option>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>


        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary" value="Search">
                </div>
                 
                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>



                </div> 

                 
            </div>




@endsection
```

report_by_user_show.blade.php

```
    @extends('admin.admin_dashboard')
    @section('admin')
    
    <div class="page-content">
        <!--breadcrumb-->
        <div class="page-breadcrumb d-none d-sm-flex align-items-center mb-3">
            <div class="breadcrumb-title pe-3">All Order By User Report</div>
            <div class="ps-3"> 
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 p-0">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="bx bx-home-alt"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Order By User Report</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-auto">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end breadcrumb-->
        <h3> Search By User Name  : {{ $userName }} </h3>
        <hr/>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sl</th>
                                <th>Date </th>
                                <th>Invoice </th>
                                <th>Amount </th>
                                <th>Payment </th>
                                <th>State </th>
                                <th>Action</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($orders as $key => $item)      
                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ $key+1 }} </td>
                                <td>{{ $item->order_date }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->invoice_no }}</td>
                                <td>AED {{ $item->amount }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->payment_method }}</td>
                                <td> <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success"> {{ $item->status }}</span></td> 
                                
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.order.details',$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-info" title="Details"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </a>
    
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.invoice.download',$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" title="Invoice Pdf"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> </a>
                                    
    
                                </td> 
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            
                            
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sl</th>
                                <th>Date </th>
                                <th>Invoice </th>
                                <th>Amount </th>
                                <th>Payment </th>
                                <th>State </th>
                                <th>Action</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    
        
    </div>

@endsection
```

ReportController.php

```
class ReportController extends Controller {
 
 public function OrderByUser(){
    $users = User::where('role','user')->latest()->get();
    return view('backend.report.report_by_user',compact('users'));

}// End Method 

public function SearchByUser(Request $request){
    $users = $request->user;
    $orders = Order::where('user_id',$users)->latest()->get();
    return view('backend.report.report_by_user_show',compact('orders','users'));
 }// End Method 
}
```

Order.php

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
 
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: <h3> Search By User Name  : {{ $orders[0]->user->name ?? $users }} </h3>

Comment: And that code does not print the name? What does it print instead? What does `$orders[0]->user`  contain in that case? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: It prints the ID of the user. And $orders[0]->user->name this throwing error as undefined array key 0 when I reused the code as <h3> Search By User Name : {{ $orders[0]->user->name }} </h3> when no order belongs to the selected user.

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - why not load the user model directly? `users->name`  could contain it?

Comment: I have edited the post and when I access users->name it throws error as: Attempt to read property "name" on string. If any more clarifications please let me know.

Comment: Dear Sir, Waiting for your response.

Comment: Sounds like `name`  is a string that you should resolve by reading the User model?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right but how do I resolve by reading the User model, I have already tried but didn't get the desired results.

Comment: Share your attempts by editing the question. Why not use something like `User::where('user_id', $users)->first()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253499/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-nico-haase).

Comment: If you are still facing any problem, please add all clarification (like coding attempts and error messages) to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified with the below statements to the  searchByUser function;

```
$users = User::select('name')->where('id', $userId)->get();      

$userName = $orders->first()->user->name ??  $users[0]['name'];

public function searchByUser(Request $request){
        $userId = $request->user;
        $orders = Order::with('user')->where('user_id', $userId)->latest()->get();
        $users = User::select('name')->where('id', $userId)->get();       
        $userName = $orders->first()->user->name ??  $users[0]['name'];
        return view('backend.report.report_by_user_show', compact('orders', 'userName'));
        }
```